# function select with autocomplete jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use function "autocomplete" of jquery.here is my code below, the problem that the  **`select`** function does not work

I initialize the variable `productId` to 0 and I changed the value in the function `**select**` this variable to 1. but still shows me 0

```
$(function () {
    var productId = 0;
    var productLabel;
    $("#autocompleteInput").autocomplete({
        source: function (req, add) {
            $.getJSON(urlresourceproduct, req, function (data) {
                add($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.tuttiProdottis,
                        val: item.id
                    };
                }));

            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            productId = 1;
            productLabel = ui.item.label;
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            alert(productId);
            drawChart();
            return false;
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $("#autocompleteInput").val("");
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: what do you mean not working?

Comment: I'll ask the same question I ask every time someone says, "It doesn't work", namely, "What happens when you try?"

Comment: as you see here I initialize the variable `productId` to 0 and I changed the value in the function `select` this variable to 1. but still shows me 0

Comment: @Berguiga.M.Amine: Does [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/536/) basically reflect what you're doing? If so I can't reproduce it.

Comment: what is that extra `});` there at the end?